# past simple or present perfect for a past action with effect on present

Tags: past-tense

> Sorry for the late reply, I was away for the weekend, I saw you had already placed another order so I owe you the extra 7€ you've spent for the shipping, let me know if you want a refund

Could have I written **spent** instead of **have spent**, **spent** because the spending of money was in the past even if the money paid correspond to the money due now

Comment: Instead of *you've spent,* it would be more natural to go for *you **paid***. Firstly because "pay" is a more common verb for such contexts, and secondly because there's no *need* to use Present Perfect (so as usual, you should naturally incline towards Simple Past).

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely write *spent* instead of *have spent*. In fact, I'd even say that it sounds more natural that way.

(You also need to separate sentences from one another- as written, you have a run-on sentence.)

> Sorry for the late reply, I was away for the weekend. I saw you had already placed another order, so I owe you the extra 7€ you spent on the shipping. Let me know if you want a refund.

Comment: Can we omit the "you" from "you spent" ?

Comment: If you do, you end up with a grammatical sentence that has the right meaning, but I wouldn't say or write it that way. Using passive participles like that is for more formal writing, which would sound stilted or pretentious here.

Answer (score 0):

> Could have I written **spent** instead of **have spent**, **spent** because the
>   spending of money was in the past even if the money paid correspond to
>   the money due now?

Yes.

These two clauses "...so I owe you the extra 7 (pounds?) **|** (that) you have spent for shipping..."

In the first clause "owe" is present tense, and you want *to express an earlier action*, which means in the next clause use past tense: *spent*.

"...so I owe you the extra 7 (pounds?) (that) you *spent* for shipping..."

With the way you have it using the Present Perfect tense, you are showing an action that started or making a statement about something that started in the past and continues up to now, which isn't true. It was an action that started and ended before now: Past Tense. [the action is the payment for shipping, of course]